# Classes not being included correctly php

Tags: php

I have three classes defined in seperate .php files:

com_dir.php:

```
<?php 
class com_dir
{
    public $name = '';
    public $author = '';
    public $date = '';
    public $version = '';
    public $summary = '';

}
?>
```

com_item.php:

```
<?php
class com_item
{
    public $name = '';
    public $type = '';
    public $full_path = '';
    public $item_vers = array()
}
?>
```

vers.php:

```
<?php
class vers
{
    public $revision;
    public $author = '';
    public $info = '';
    public $date = '';
}
?>
```

They are in the same directory as my index.php file:

```
<?php

include dirname(__FILE__).'/com_dir.php';
include dirname(__FILE__).'/com_item.php';
include dirname(__FILE__).'/vers.php';

    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $xml_log = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/svn_log.xml');
    $xml_list = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/svn_list.xml');

    //irrelevant filler

    $com_list = array();
    $rev_list = array();

    foreach ($xml_list->list as $list)
    {
        foreach($list->entry as $entry)
        {
            if ($entry['kind'] == 'dir' && (!in_array($entry -> $commit[0]['revision'], $rev_list)))
            {
                array_push($rev_list, $entry -> $commit[0]['revision']);

                $temp = new com_dir(); //problem line
                $temp->name = $entry->name;
                echo("worked");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I get the error: `Fatal error: Class 'com_dir' not found in /home/collin/Desktop/Assignment3.0/index.php on line 52`

Am I not including them properly to be able to create class instances from them?

Comment: Is something in the error log? Returns dirname the Folder with a trailing slash?

Comment: Change `include` to `require` and see what happens. `Include` will allow for errors when including the file. `Require` does not: If loading the file has errors, the script will be terminated. Obviously you NEED those classes, so there is no margin of error if they cannot be loaded.

Comment: @Sven After changing it to require and refreshing the page, nothing occurs. Just a blank page (I assume this means the script was terminated.) So there must be something wrong with my filepath? I'm not sure how..

Comment: Are you sure, that you are not missing a `/`in your include path?

Comment: @jdo I think I was, yes. But after making the fix the script is still terminating

Comment: A blank page can be changed. Enable `display_errors` to get a meaningful error message: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the start of your script. You might also want to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get ALL reasons for errors.

Comment: How about calling ini_set('display_errors',1); before the include? Also do you have shell access? then you can run php index.php from the command line to see if any errors occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in including `com_item.php`. There was no trailing semicolon in `public $item_vers = array()`. I would have caught this had I moved `ini_set` and `error_reporting` to be before my include statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your path.

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once BASE_PATH . '/com_dir.php';
```